# WebAudio play sound pops at start and end

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Whenever I play a sound using code such as

```
// binaryData = a wave file from a websocket
let ctx = new AudioContext();
ctx.decodeAudioData(binaryData, function(audioData){
   let source = ctx.createBufferSource();
   source.buffer = audioData;
   source.connect(ctx.destination);
   source.start(0);
});
```

There is a very audible click or pop between each clip played. Forget the fact that I'm trying to play real-time audio with this system; why is it that there is a glitchy noise at the beginning and end of each sound clip played? I'm not understanding how this is acceptable behaviour in 2017 from an audio playing device... Is there any way to mitigate or eliminate this?

---

**Answer**

Following the answer below here is a good set of #s to use to reduce clicking to basically nothing. I'm not saying this works great for a tone, but its flawless for voice.

```
// start of clip
// clipPlayTime may be 0 or your scheduled play time
gain.setValueAtTime(0.01, clipPlayTime);
gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(1, clipPlayTime + 0.001);
// end of clip
gain.setValueAtTime(1, clipPlayTime + clipLength - 0.001);
gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.01, clipPlayTime + clipLength);
```

This creates a ramp up and a ramp down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`exponentialRampToValueAtTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/exponentialRampToValueAtTime) to remove (or atleast reduce) the clicking noise.

Here's a great explanation: [Web Audio, the ugly click and the human ear](http://alemangui.github.io/blog//2015/12/26/ramp-to-value.html)

---

**Full Example**

Base example taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData

```
<button class="play">Play</button>
<button class="stop">Stop</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var source;
var play = document.querySelector('.play');
var stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();


function getData() {
    source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', './sample.wav', true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.onload = function() {
        var audioData = request.response;

        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
                source.buffer = buffer;
                source.connect(gainNode);
                gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
                gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, audioCtx.currentTime);
            },

            function(e) {
                console.log("Error with decoding audio data" + e.err);
            });
    }
    request.send();
}


play.onclick = function() {
    getData();
    source.start(0);
    play.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}

stop.onclick = function() {
    gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(gainNode.gain.value, audioCtx.currentTime);
    gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.0001, audioCtx.currentTime + 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
        source.stop();
    }, 1000)
    play.removeAttribute('disabled');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Updated article link: https://alemangui.github.io/ramp-to-value