# How to implement exponentialRampToValueAtTime in order to remove clicking sound when writing audio via websocket

Tags: java, audio, websocket

I am writing audio stream via websocket for a telephony application. Just before the audio starts playing there is a distinct 'click'. Upon further research, I came across the following question in SO,

[WebAudio play sound pops at start and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996114/webaudio-play-sound-pops-at-start-and-end/47997099)

The accepted answer in the above question states to the `exponentialRampToValueAtTime` API to remove the said noise. I am implementing my service in Java and do not have access to specific API. How do I go about implementing an `exponentialRampToValueAtTime` method to attenuate the noise in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code to handle the clicking problem for some sound-based applications. IDK that the algorithm I came up with is considered robust, but it seems to be working. I'd categorize it as "reinventing the wheel". The algorithm uses a linear ramp, not exponential. It shouldn't be too hard to make the increments exponential instead.

Basic overview:

1. Obtain the byte data from the line
2. convert the byte data to PCM
3. for the starting 1024 pcm frames (a smaller number may be fine, especially if an exponential ramp is used instead of the linear), multiply each frame by a sequence that progresses from 0 to 1.

I use the following linear formula and have gotten satisfactory results.

for n = 0 to 1024

```
pcmValue[n] *= n / 1024;
```

4. convert the PCM back to bytes and ship

This only has to be done for the starts or the ends (algorithm in reverse).

For exponential, I'm guessing something like the following might work:

```
pcmValue[n] *= (Math.pow(2, n/1024) - 1);
```

A function related to decibels might have even better spaced increments. The better the spacing, the fewer the number of PCM frames needed to prevent the click.

In [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/adonax/audiocue/AudioCue.java), there is a need to ensure smooth transitions when a sound receives real-time commands to change volume. I use the same basic idea described above, but with a linear ramp between the two volume levels. Code for handling the increments can be seen at lines 1200, 892 and 1302. Using a linear ramp allows for a one-time calculation followed by simple addition for the individual PCM frames. But as I said, I wrote this from scratch and a better-schooled or more experienced audio engineer will likely have further insights or improvements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Quick question, how do I convert byte to PCM? Sorry not very familiar with audio stuff.

Comment: I think this has been answered a couple times already and a simple search should bring it up for you. In the code base linked above, there is an example in the "load" method, for incoming 16-bit, 44100 fps, stereo, little-endian. The process varies, depending upon the format of the file.